# asp.net c# Label name increse

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, label

I'm just tried the change label name with a "foreach" loop but Visual Studio returned error to me.

I just tried to use the label in a "foreach" loop and wanted to make my work easier. The code is just like that.

```
 int i = 0;

        foreach (string a in dr)
        {
            Label6.Text = dr.GetString(i).ToString();
            i++;
        }
```

I don't understand why i can't use like this.

```
Label[i], Label(i) or label{i}
```

Can anyone know how can i use like this? Thanks for support :)

Comment: Because you don't immediately have an array of `Label`s named `Label`. They all have distinct names. There will be a collection of them referenced in a container, but I think there's a lot more for someone to explain here than just provide a solution. That is, ignoring the fact that your loop looked flawed.

Comment: What is dr in this example? I assume it is a DataRow object (wild guess)? Are you trying to get data from something and put it into a label?

Comment: But i created Label6,Label7,...,Label12. And i want a code like Label[i+6] for that

Comment: @JonVD DR is variable of Oracle Data Reader. I create a string that includes an oracle call. And then i read it with DR. Now with this foreach loop, i want to assign values to different labels. Thats all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels on your page do not compound an array. If you have say 6 Labels - this just 6 labels with 6 different IDs. That does not prevent you from naming them `FirstLabel`, `SecondLabel`, etc - and suddenly they cannot be accessed like an array.

However if you really named them `Label1` through `Label6` and what to leverage that fact - you can try using `FindControl` method:

```
int i = 6;
Label label = FindControl("Label" + i) as Label;
```

Note that `FindControl` is not recursive - you have to call it on the label's closest container, which is not always the page itself.